# Writing a function in SSRS that is depended on the toggle state being true or false

Tags: sql, reporting-services, toggle

I have a drill through and drill down functionality together in one report. My report first shows summary data and then if users toggle data (drill down functionality) then it gives detail information. I also have a drill through functionality on the summary data.
Example of my report:
Summary Report as not toggled:

```
 ProductType  ProductLocation  ProductCountA  ProductionCountB  Total
+Electronic                    3              4                 7
```

Summary Report as toggled

```
 ProductType  ProductLocation  ProductCountA  ProductionCountB  Total
-Electronic   USA              1              2                 5
              Mexico           2              2                 2
```

I have created drill through action on summary data that will work on toggled and non toggled product counts. I have created an "ALL" Product location for when data is not toggeled. What is the function for recognizing if ProductLocation is toggled or not? If its not toggled then I will pass "ALL" value to the ProductLocation parameter if its toggled then I will pass the ProductionLoacation field value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my own question and would like to post for others:
ADD this function to the ProductionLocation value field under action:

```
=IIF(inscope("ProductLocationGroup"),Fields!ProductionLocation.Value,"ALL")
```

This checks to see if the ProductionLocationGroup (Use group name) group is in scope or not. If its not toggled that means its not in scope, if it is toggled then it will be in scope